# requirejs unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, requirejs, load-order

```
// conifg.js
require.config({
  paths: {
    'main': 'main',
    'socketio': './libs/socket.io/socket.io',
    'plotly': './libs/plotly/plotly-latest.min',
    'renderDataToPlotly': './scripts/renderDataToPlotly',
    'jquery': './libs/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min',
    'jqueryUI': './libs/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.min',
    'sliders': './scripts/sliders',
    'makePlotlyWindowResponsive': './scripts/makePlotlyWindowResponsive'
  },
  shim: {                  
    'jqueryUI': ['jquery'] 
  }
});

require(['main']);

// main.js
define([
  'jquery',
  'jqueryUI',
  'socketio',
  'sliders',
  'makePlotlyWindowResponsive',
  'renderDataToPlotly'
  ],
  function($, ui, io, sliders, makePlotlyWindowResponsive, renderDataToPlotly) {
    //
  }
);

// renderDataToPlotly.js and makePlotlyWindowResponsive.js
define(['plotly'], function() {

});
```

When I load the page I get this load order:
[image]
As you can see, `makePlotlyWindowResponsive.js` (1, on image) loads before `plotly-latest.min.js` (2, on image). As I understand requirejs mechanics, I would spect a `Plotly is not defined` error on `makePlotlyWindowResponsive.js`, but I'm not getting any. Everything works.

I want to understand requirejs and how it works.

**Question 1**: How there is not an error?

**Question 2**: That means that, despite load order, there is no error if files are loaded before page is fully loaded?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The relative order you witnessed between `plotly.min.js` and the modules that depend on it is necessary**. RequireJS has no reason to fetch `plotly.min.js` until `makePlotlyWindowResponsive` or `renderDataToPlotly` have been fetched.

Terminological note: I say "fetching (a module)" for the action of issuing an HTTP query on the network and I'll use "defining (a module)" for the action of running the factory function of a module. The term "loading" is too ambiguous.

What happens is:

1. You require `main`. So RequireJS fetches `main`.
2. RequireJS executes the `define` in `main`. The factory (the callback) cannot be run until the dependencies are defined themselves. So it initiates fetching the dependencies. This fetching can happen in any order. Among the dependencies are `makePlotlyWindowResponsive` and `renderDataToPlotly`.
3. RequireJS fetches `makePlotlyWindowResponsive` and `renderDataToPlotly`. (Their relative order does not matter.)
4. RequireJS executes the `define` of either `makePlotlyWindowResponsive` or `renderDataToPlotly`. **This is where it learns that it must fetch the module `plotly` which resolves to `./libs/plotly/plotly-latest.min.js`.** Before this point, RequireJS has no idea that `plotly` will be needed. The fact that it is among the `paths` is not a sufficient condition to trigger its loading.
5. RequireJS fetches `./libs/plotly/plotly-latest.min.js`.

Comment: I found why wasn't working. If you are curious about it, I will post an answer on the new question link.

Answer (score 1):

When requirejs receives a script from the network, it runs that script. the `require` (or `define`?) function says "download these other scripts, then run them, and once you've got all their return values, run this function". So it waits for the other scripts to load and return their values before calling the function in this one. In short, the order in which they load may not be the same as the order in which their functions run.

Comment: I think you're right @David Knipe. Download the file does not mean running it. For example: `makePlotlyWindowResponsive.js` is downloaded before `plotly-latest.min.js`but requirejs runs first this last one and then the first downloaded one, as was defined by the `define()`function. Am I getting this right?

Comment: Yes. Or more precisely, it first runs the bit of `makePlotlyWindowResponsive.js` that tells it what the dependencies are, but not the main function. That causes it to download and run `plotly-latest.min.js` (assuming it hasn't already been run). Once it's done that, it runs the function in `makePlotlyWindowResponsive.js`, presumably using the output from `plotly-latest.min.js` as an argument.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think understanding this little things can make a huge difference. Have a nice day @David Knipe